# Не выводятся символы кириллицы в заголовках ноды

Tags: drupal, кодировка

Подскажите как исправить, Drupal 7.8, шаблон govideo, в загаловках ноды страницы выводится только символы юникода, хотя в коде страницы отображается все нормально.
`nelegalom . . 1` - так выглядит на странице,
`<h2 class="heading">nelegalom по Чернобыльской зоне. Сталк с МШ. Часть1</h2>` - так в коде страницы
Подскажите что изменить для отображения кириллицы?

*Обновление*

Посмотрел внимательно css, шрифты в норме, добавил чтоб наверняка Arial. В одном месте выводятся кириллические символы, код такой:

```
<a href="#" class="toc">
    <span class="thumb"><?php if (isset($fields['field_video']->content)) { print $fields['field_video']->content; } if (isset($fields['field_teaserimage']->content)) { print $fields['field_teaserimage']->content; } else { if (isset($fields['field_embeddedvideo']->content)) { print $fields['field_embeddedvideo']->content; }}  ?></span>
    <span class="desc">
    <span class="title"><?php print $fields['title']->content; ?></span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Проблема заключалась в отсутствии кириллических символов в подключаемом js шрифта

Answer (score 1):

Я бы советовал вам найти в папке templat'a(шаблона) файл node.phtml(или как-то так, шаблон ноды) и перекодировать сам файл либо в utf-8 либо в windows-1251, например при помощи sublime или notepad++ или чем-то что умеет это делать. В зависимости от того, какая кодировка на всём сайте.
п.с. Какой у вас template?